# World cup group stage draw algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am making an world cup group stage draw website.
I have some problem with algorithm when I check if any  with certain classes already have  with same class

Find and put an img into an empty td is working but browser doesn't check if any  with certain classes already have  a child img with same class.

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

result:

[image]

```js
var teamList = $('div.seeds img');
var counter=0;

var continentClass, seedClass, currentTeam;
$('button').on('click',function(){
 if(counter<=30) 
  getTeam();
 else
  alert('No more team is allowed');
});

function getTeam(){
 // count image tags
 currentTeam=teamList.eq(counter);
 //get the second and first class of img tag
 continentClass = currentTeam.attr('class').split(' ')[0];
 seedClass = currentTeam.attr('class').split(' ')[1];
 setGroups();
 currentTeam.fadeOut();
 counter = counter +1;
}

function setGroups(){
 //find td tag which has a parent with same class as the img tag 
 var activeTD = $('tr.'+seedClass + ' td');
 while(true){
  //find a random TD and repeat while loop if the tag has any child 
  var randomTD = activeTD.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*activeTD.length));
  if(randomTD.children().length==0){
   //break while-loop if function returns true
   //td as parameter
   if(checkDuplication(randomTD))
    break;
  }
 }
}
function checkDuplication(tableTD){
 
 //get the class of randomly chosen td tag
 var getGroupClass = tableTD.attr('class');
 //all td with same group class
 var sameGroups = $('td.'+getGroupClass);
 //console.log(sameGroups.children().attr('class'));
 //console.log('img :' +$('td.'+getGroupClass).children('img').attr('src'));
 if(sameGroups.children(continentClass).not('.europe').length>0){
  console.log('exists already');
  return false;
 }else if(continentClass == 'europe' && sameGroups.children(continentClass).length>1){
  console.log('only 2 european countries per group');
  return false;
 }
 else{
  console.log('counter :'+ counter + ' '+sameGroups);
  tableTD.html('<img src="' + currentTeam.attr('src') + '" class="' + currentTeam.attr('class') + currentTeam.data('name')+'">');
  return true;
 }
 /*if((continentClass !='europe') && sameGroups.children(continentClass).length==0){
  console.log('counter :'+ counter + ' '+sameGroups);
  tableTD.html('<img src="' + currentTeam.attr('src') + '" class="' + currentTeam.attr('class') + currentTeam.data('name')+'">');
  return true;
 }else if(sameGroups.children(continentClass).not('.europe').length>0){
  console.log('no two countries from same continent');
  return false;
 }else if(continentClass == 'europe' && sameGroups.children(continentClass).length>1){
  console.log('just two european countries per group');
  return false;
 }*/
 /*$('td.'+getGroupClass).each(function(index){
  if($(this).find(continentClass).not('.europe').length>0){
   return false;
  }else if(continentClass=='europe' && $(this).find(continentClass).length>1){
   return false;
  } else{
   tableTD.html('<img src="' + currentTeam.attr('src') + '" class="' + currentTeam.attr('class') + currentTeam.data('name') + '">');
   return false;
  }
 });*/
}
```

```css
body,html{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
header{
 background-image:url('https://assets.hrc.org//files/images/blog/Russia-Flag-1600x900.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 height:150px;
 width:100%;
 padding-top:10px;
 color:yellow;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align:center;
}
header h1{
 line-height:100px;
}
div.seeds{
 float:right;
 width:500px;
 background-color:lightblue;
 height:850px;
 font-size:0;
 text-align:center;
}

div.seeds div h1{
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:18px;
 margin:10px;
}
/*div.seeds div:first-child, div.seeds div:nth-child(2n){*/
div.seeds div{
 vertical-align:top;
}
div.seeds div:nth-child(-n+4){
 display:inline-block;
 width:120px;
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
div.seeds img{
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 padding:10px;
}
div.main button{
 border:none;
 border-radius:3px;
 padding:15px;
 font-size:15px;
 display:block;
}
table{
 margin-top:10px;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 text-align:center;
}
table thead tr{
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
td img{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   <h1>Russia world cup</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="seeds">
   <div class="firstSeed">
    <h1>First seed</h1>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/1200px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png" class="europe first" data-name=" Germany">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Brazil.svg.png" class="southAmerica first" data-name=" Brazil">
    <img src="https://southcoastherald.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sites/52/2015/03/portuguese-flag-wikipedia.jpg" class="europe first" data-name=" Portugal">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Flag_de_Marina_Argentina_%281818%29.svg/2000px-Flag_de_Marina_Argentina_%281818%29.svg.png" class="southAmerica first" data-name=" Argentina">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Belgium.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Belgium.svg.png" class="europe first" data-name=" Belgium">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Zastava_Kranja.svg/800px-Zastava_Kranja.svg.png" class="europe first" data-name=" Poland">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/1280px-Flag_of_France.svg.png" class="europe first" data-name=" France">
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Second seed</h1>
    <img src="http://static.donquijote.org/images/culture/spanish_flag2.jpg" class="europe second" data-name=" Spain">
    <img src="http://peruflag.facts.co/peruflagof/PeruFlagImage.jpg" class="southAmerica second" data-name=" Peru">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Civil_Ensign_of_Switzerland.svg/320px-Civil_Ensign_of_Switzerland.svg.png" class="europe second" data-name=" Switzerland">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/be/Flag_of_England.svg/1200px-Flag_of_England.svg.png" class="europe second" data-name=" England">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Flag_of_Colombia.svg/255px-Flag_of_Colombia.svg.png" class="southAmerica second" data-name=" Colombia">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Flag_of_Mexico.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Mexico.svg.png" class="northCentralAmerica second" data-name=" Mexico">
    <img src="http://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/flags/countrys/zzzflags/uylarge.gif" class="southAmerica second" data-name=" Uruguay">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Flag_of_Croatia.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Croatia.svg.png" class="europe second" data-name=" Croatia">
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Third seed</h1>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png" class="europe third" data-name=" Denmark">
    <img src="http://icelandflag.facts.co/icelandflagof/IcelandFlagImage.png" class="europe third" data-name=" Iceland">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Flag_of_Costa_Rica_%28state%29.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Costa_Rica_%28state%29.svg.png" class="northCentralAmerica third" data-name=" Costa_Rica">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31QFtg6TJdL.jpg" class="europe third" data-name=" Sweden">
    <img src="http://www.flagfocus.info/images/Flags/Tunisia.png" class="africa third" data-name=" Tunisia">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Flag_of_Egypt_%28variant%29.png" class="africa third" data-name=" Egypt">
    <img src="http://flagpedia.net/data/flags/ultra/sn.png" class="africa third" data-name=" Senegal">
    <img src="https://jsis.washington.edu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/iran-162321_640.png" class="asia third" data-name=" Iran">
   </div>
   <div> 
    <h1>Forth seed</h1>
    <img src="http://flagpedia.net/data/flags/ultra/rs.png" class="europe forth" data-name=" Serbia">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Flag_of_Nigeria.png/1024px-Flag_of_Nigeria.png" class="africa forth" data-name=" Nigeria">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b9/Flag_of_Australia.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Australia.svg.png" class="asia forth" data-name=" Australia">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9e/Flag_of_Japan.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Japan.svg.png" class="asia forth" data-name="J apan">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Morocco_%28unbordered_light_green%29.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Morocco_%28unbordered_light_green%29.svg.png" class="africa forth" data-name=" Morocco">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Flag_of_Panama.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Panama.svg.png" class="northCentralAmerica forth" data-name=" Panama">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Flag_of_South_Korea.png" class="asia forth" data-name=" South_Korea">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png" class="asia forth" data-name=" Saudi_Arabia">
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Group A:</th>
      <th>Group B:</th>
      <th>Group C:</th>
      <th>Group D:</th>
      <th>Group E:</th>
      <th>Group F:</th>
      <th>Group G:</th>
      <th>Group H:</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="first">
     <td class="groupA"><img class="europe" data-name="Russia" src="https://assets.hrc.org//files/images/blog/Russia-Flag-1600x900.jpg"></td>
     <td class="groupB"></td>
     <td class="groupC"></td>
     <td class="groupD"></td>
     <td class="groupE"></td>
     <td class="groupF"></td>
     <td class="groupG"></td>
     <td class="groupH"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second">
     <td class="groupA"></td>
     <td class="groupB"></td>
     <td class="groupC"></td>
     <td class="groupD"></td>
     <td class="groupE"></td>
     <td class="groupF"></td>
     <td class="groupG"></td>
     <td class="groupH"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="third">
     <td class="groupA"></td>
     <td class="groupB"></td>
     <td class="groupC"></td>
     <td class="groupD"></td>
     <td class="groupE"></td>
     <td class="groupF"></td>
     <td class="groupG"></td>
     <td class="groupH"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="forth">
     <td class="groupA"></td>
     <td class="groupB"></td>
     <td class="groupC"></td>
     <td class="groupD"></td>
     <td class="groupE"></td>
     <td class="groupF"></td>
     <td class="groupG"></td>
     <td class="groupH"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <button class="put">Put team</button>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bmjytuxj/show/
https://jsfiddle.net/bmjytuxj/

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with placeholder.com or other images and create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan ok. Then i will upload my full code

Comment: Please note the "MINIMAL" in the [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I tried add css into snippet but it says Your post appears to contain code…It doesn't allow me edit snippet

Comment: No style tags in The CSS pane

Comment: @mplungjan Yes. I know that . Maybe I should ask question next time with different code

Comment: Just paste raw CSS into the CSS pane. Also give us a step by step guide what to click to see the problem

Comment: @mplungjan sorry editing snippet didn't work. So I added jsfiddle

Comment: I had not problem. But what do I need to do to show the problem? I can click as many times on put team as I want and all teams are copied one by one

Comment: @mplungjan Really sorry for my poor english. If you look at the code, you can see there are 4 <tr> and 8 <td> in every <tr>. td have group classes. Example: td.groupC. So td is like a group and the world cup group stage draw rule is, if the continent is not europe, no more than 1 country from the same continent can be placed in the same group.(no argentina and columbia in same group)  If the continent is europe, the limit is 2. Problem with the code is browser just ignores these limitations.